# Javascript Empty String Comparison

Tags: javascript, comparison

I don't understand why one scenario evaluates false and the other true.

Scenario 1:

```
> '' == ''
true
```

Scenario 2:

```
> '' == ('' || undefined)
false
```

Is scenario 2 not asking if (empty string) is equal to: (empty string) OR undefined?

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental here, which is really what I'm trying to figure out. I can easily code around this, but I'd like to learn *why* it's happening... for next time, ya know?

Comment: your question is just like saying that `2 == 3 || 2` is testing if 2 equals 3 or 2. If you really stop to think about it as a computer would read it, you can see that it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
'' == ( '' || undefined )
```

Is not the same as

```
( '' == '' ) || ( '' == undefined )
```

It's more along the lines of:

```
var foo = '' || undefined; // Results in undefined
```

And then comparing `foo` to an empty string:

```
foo == ''; // undefined == '' will result in false
```

#### Explanation

The logical `||` is a short-circuiting operator. If the argument to its left is *truthy*, the argument to the right is not even evaluated. In JavaScript, `''` is not considered to be *truthy*:

```
if ( '' ) console.log( 'Empty Strings are True?' );
```

As such `undefined` is returned and compared against an empty string. When you perform this logic within a the parenthesis, the `''` and the `undefined` don't know about the impending equality check that is waiting to happen - they just want to know which of them is going to survive this evaluation.

Comment: "When you perform this logic within a the parenthesis, the `''` and the `undefined` don't know about the impending equality check that is waiting to happen"  
That was what made it click for me. Thanks very much @JonathanSampson

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it:

```
'' == ('' || undefined) // return "undefined"
'' == undefined // false
```

`||` return the first true value or the **last value**.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cjRXU/)

You want this:

```
'' == undefined  || '' == false
```

---

`undefined` is `==` only to `null`, and not to all other "falsy" values:

- 0
- "" - empty string
- NaN
- false

Comment: "|| return the first true value or the last value." - that made me understand how that operator works and why (a || a === 0) is false and (a === 0 || a) is "" when a = "". thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try `'' == '' || '' == undefined`

As in almost all programming languages, the expressions at both sides of an operator must evaluate to a valid operand. `||` is logical OR operator which is used to evaluate a pair of boolean operands.

Comment: what do you mean by "`||` is logical OR which requires a pair of boolean expressions"

Comment: `||` doesn't require to boolean expressions!

Comment: @gdoron boolean expression is one that results a value of true or false. (true || false) is an expression as well as ((true && false)||(false||false)). In both cases you require a boolean expression on each side of the logical operator.

Comment: But it's not true... you can write `var x = 0 || '' || 3|| null; alert(x) // 3`

Comment: @gdoron in JS anything can evaluate to a Boolean value.